# React Styled Component SVG styling isn't displaying properly?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

So, I am trying to change the color of my svg icon, but it isn't changing color. When I inspect the page, it clearly shows the color is showing in the CSS and it is not crossed out, yet it is just a default black color.

Here is my code,

```
      const SearchIcon = styled.span`
        color: #9aa0a6;
        height: 44px;
        width: 33px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
      `;


     <SearchIcon>
          <svg
            focusable='false'
            xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
            viewBox='0 0 24 24'
          >
            <path d='M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z' />
          </svg>
        </SearchIcon>
```

I don't get why my svg isn't changing color. Even if I nest it inside, it doesn't do anything.

For example

```
      const SearchIcon = styled.span`
        color: #9aa0a6;
        height: 44px;
        width: 33px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;

       svg {
       color: red;
       }
      `;
```

and this still does nothing to the color.

Any idea why my svg isn't getting styled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/color) it seems the `color` attribute *should* provide an indirect `currentcolor` value, but I'm not exactly sure why it's not inherited either. Well, the `color` attribute is inherited all the way through to the `path` element, but isn't actually changing the color.

[image]

You can specify the `fill` CSS rule as well.

```
const SearchIcon = styled.span`
  color: #9aa0a6;
  height: 44px;
  width: 33px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;

  & svg {
    fill: #9aa0a6;
  }
`;
```

[image]

## Update

Tip of the hat to @SeanW.

The `color` CSS rule only sets the "currentColor" value, but you must still explicitly set the `fill`, `stroke`, `stop-color`, `flood-color`, and `lighting-color` attributes manually to `"currentColor"`.

```
const SearchIcon = styled.span`
  color: #9aa0a6;
  height: 44px;
  width: 33px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
`;

<SearchIcon>
  <svg
    focusable="false"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
    fill="currentColor" // <-- inherits the current color
  >
    <path d="M15.5 14h-.79l-.28-.27A6.471 6.471 0 0 0 16 9.5 6.5 6.5 0 1 0 9.5 16c1.61 0 3.09-.59 4.23-1.57l.27.28v.79l5 4.99L20.49 19l-4.99-5zm-6 0C7.01 14 5 11.99 5 9.5S7.01 5 9.5 5 14 7.01 14 9.5 11.99 14 9.5 14z" />
  </svg>
</SearchIcon>
```

Comment: The browser won't inherit the text color unless the fill rule is explicitly set - <svg fill="currentColor"

Comment: @SeanW Ah, OFC... I do see that buried a little deeper in the very docs I linked. Thanks.